# knockout baseEntity property availability is confusing

Tags: javascript, inheritance, knockout.js, durandal

I am trying to implement a baseEntity class for entities such as user and groups but `isFavourite` property can not read the correct `Id()` from `persistanceId()` when it is in baseEntity. (`type` and `Id()` come out as undefined and surprisingly type has the correct value in `confirmDelete`)

```
define(["knockout"], function (ko) {
    var app = require('durandal/app');
    ko.baseEntity = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.Id = ko.observable();
        self.confirmDelete = function () {
            var result;
            app.showMessage(
                'Are you sure you want to delete the ' + self.type + ' ' + self.Name() + '?',
                'Deleting ' + self.type, ['Yes', 'No']).then(
                function (dialogResult) {
                    dialogResult === "Yes" ? result = true : result = false;
                });
            return result;
        };
        self.persistanceId = function () {
            return self.type + '-' + self.Id() + "-IsFavourite";
        };
        self.isFavourite = ko.observable(false).extend({
            persist: self.persistanceId()
        });
        self.toggleFavourite = function () {
            self.isFavourite(!self.isFavourite());
        };
    }
    return {
        model: ko.baseEntity
    }
});
```

but if `isFavourite` instead of being here in baseEntity it is for example part of group then it works fine.

```
define(["knockout", "models/baseentity"], function (ko, baseEntity) {
    var
    model = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        baseEntity.model.call(self);
        self.type = 'group';
        self.Id(data.Id);
        self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        self.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
        self.Members = ko.observableArray(data.Members);
        self.isFavourite = ko.observable(false).extend({
            persist: self.persistanceId()
        });
    }
    return {
        model: model
    }
});
```

Could someone explain to me what is going on here and how can I move my base property back in my baseentity as it is shared across various other things too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't follow why you would want to modify the knockout object itself? I believe Dave Lowe is correct in suggesting that you do this in JavaScript alone. Properties on your model, to the extent that they affect your view, should be observable, but your model doesn't need to be attached to knockout.

Also, consider spending some time at http://objectplayground.com, which has a great tutorial on learning object oriented JavaScript. Your paradigm should look a little more like this:

```
function Model(obj) {

    this.attribute = obj.attribute;

    this.observable = ko.observable(obj.observable);

    this.localFunction = function(val) {
        if (obj.attr == true) this.observable(val);
    };
}

Model.prototype.globalFunction = function(data) {
    this.observable(data);
};
```

Notice, in particular, that if the method depends on the local variable, that is, the argument passed to the constructor, then it needs to be defined in the constructor. Otherwise, you should define methods on the prototype.

This paradigm works excellently with require in durandal since you can do the following:

```
define(function(require) {
    var Model = require('model');
    var object = new Model({});
})
```

Comment: Yeah understood that ko.baseEntity was stupid, but still have to leave some of the base Model props as knockout props as they are mainly used for view's data binding. Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, definitely doable. If you set an attribute a as a ko.observable on Model, and then create a SpecialModel constructor and set SpecialModel.prototype = new Model(), SpecialModel will have an observable attribute a and you can call something like this.a('abc') right in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I am no javascript master but i would look to decouple the inheritance of your model hierarchy from knockout - does the model behave as expected if you implement it vanilla?

Answer (score 0):

OK, apparently the easier way to do this subClass business in ko is using ko itself. Who would have thought :)

So now I have defined my base model to be:

```
define(["knockout"], function (ko) {
    var app = require('durandal/app');
    ko.baseEntity = function (type, data) {
        var self = this;
        self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
        self.Type = ko.observable(type);
        self.Name = ko.observable();
        self.persistanceId = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.Type() + '-' + self.Id() + "-IsFavourite";
        });
        self.isFavourite = ko.observable(false).extend({
            persist: self.persistanceId()
        });
        self.toggleFavourite = function () {
            self.isFavourite(!self.isFavourite());
        };
        self.confirmDelete = function () {
            var result;
            app.showMessage('Are you sure you want to delete the ' + self.Type() + ' ' + self.Name() + '?', 'Deleting ' + self.Type(), ['Yes', 'No'])
                .then(function (dialogResult) {
                    dialogResult === "Yes" ? result = true : result = false;
                });
            return result;
        };
    }
    return {
        model: ko.baseEntity
    }
});
```

As you can see I have now added the same data parameter that I pass into my concrete implementation. This is possible as later I will use `ko.utils.extend` to create an instance of this and extend it:

```
define(["knockout", "models/baseentity", "config"], function (ko, baseEntity, config) {
    var
    model = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        ko.utils.extend(self, new baseEntity.model(config.subClassTypes.user, data));
        self.Id(data.Id);
        self.FirstName = ko.observable(data.FirstName);
        self.LastName = ko.observable(data.LastName);
        self.JobTitle = ko.observable(data.JobTitle);
        self.UserLevel = ko.observable(data.UserLevel);
        self.Groups = ko.observableArray(data.Groups);
        self.ImageUrl = data.ImageUrl;
        self.Name(self.FirstName() + ' ' + self.LastName());
    }
    return {
        model: model
    }
});
```

another subclass example:

```
define(["knockout", "models/baseentity", "config"], function (ko, baseEntity, config) {
    var
    model = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        ko.utils.extend(self, new baseEntity.model(config.subClassTypes.group, data));
        self.Id(data.Id);
        self.Name(data.Name);
        self.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
        self.Members = ko.observableArray(data.Members);       
    }
    return {
        model: model
    }
});
```

This way I have managed to get my methods transferred over to the base and it works fine. I hate answering my own questions, so waiting for someone to add some nice valuable answers I can tick.